# How can I run a class method stored in a variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, class-method

I have the following class:

```
Class ImportData{
    $importSource
    $importUser
    $importPass
    $importType

    ImportData(){

    }

    [void]GetImportData($id){
        $srcQuery = "SELECT * FROM [$global:sqlDB].[dbo].table WHERE id=$id"
        $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $srcQuery -ServerInstance $global:sqlhost -Database $global:sqlDB
        $srcAddress = "https://"+$result.impAddress
        $srcUser = $result.impUser
        $srcPass = $result.impPassword
        $srcAuth = if($result.authoritative -eq 1) { $true } else { $false }
        $srcType = $result.importType
        $command = "Query$srcType($srcAddress,$srcUser,$srcPass)"
        & $command
        Write-Host $command
        Invoke-Expression $command -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable SearchError
    }

    [void]Queryapi($Address,$User,$Password){
        Write-Host "Ran Queryapi method on Class Type: ImportData"
    }

    [void]processImport($data){

    }
}
```

When trying to run the dynamic call

> Invoke-Expression $command -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable
>   SearchError

or `& $command`, it will not allow me to run it because it isn't a command. But a method within my class.

**Is there a way to call a method dynamically based off a result set that has been returned from a query?**

As seen in the code I have tried the `Invoke-Expression` and the `&` process as well. But to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't need `Invoke-Expression` at all here. 
Powershell support natively dynamic invocation based on the function name string

You only need to specify that you want to execute the class method by using the `$this` keyword then call the function dynamically like this.

`$command = $this."Query$srcType"($srcAddress,$srcUser,$srcPass)`

**References**

[About_Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-6)